# How to create Order By in my SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

How can i create a Order By in my sql statement? I already tried in a statement like this but this does not work. It crashes every time i run it. Is it because of my $_GET['email']? What am i doing wrong?

```
$results = $this->EE->db->query(
"SELECT ct.*, t.*, em.*, cd.*
FROM transactions as t
Inner JOIN exp_channel_titles as ct on (t.restaurant_id = ct.entry_id)
Inner JOIN exp_channel_data as cd on (ct.entry_id = cd.entry_id)
inner join exp_members as em on (t.cardid-10000000 = em.member_id) 
WHERE ct.title = '".$_GET['email']."'ORDER BY t.created DESC");
```

Comment: There is one space missing before `'ORDER BY'`

Comment: Beware of malicious input, you should sanitase your input or better yet use some king of prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, you missed one space before `'ORDER BY'`.

From

```
WHERE ct.title = '".$_GET['email']."'ORDER BY t.created DESC");
                                   ^^^
```

to

```
WHERE ct.title = '".$_GET['email']." 'ORDER BY t.created DESC");
                                   ^^^^
```

All together:

```
$results = $this->EE->db->query(
"SELECT ct.*, t.*, em.*, cd.*
FROM transactions as t
Inner JOIN exp_channel_titles as ct on (t.restaurant_id = ct.entry_id)
Inner JOIN exp_channel_data as cd on (ct.entry_id = cd.entry_id)
inner join exp_members as em on (t.cardid-10000000 = em.member_id) 
WHERE ct.title = '".$_GET['email']." 'ORDER BY t.created DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

shoule be :

```
$results = $this->EE->db->query(
"SELECT ct.*, t.*, em.*, cd.*
FROM transactions as t
Inner JOIN exp_channel_titles as ct on (t.restaurant_id = ct.entry_id)
Inner JOIN exp_channel_data as cd on (ct.entry_id = cd.entry_id)
inner join exp_members as em on (t.cardid-10000000 = em.member_id) 
WHERE ct.title = '".$_GET['email']."' ORDER BY t.created DESC");
```

There is space missing between `$_GET['email']` and `ORDER BY` .

Answer (score 0):

Use seperate variables for readability.

```
$email  =   $_GET['email'];

$query  =   "SELECT
              ct.*,
              t.*,
              em.*,
              cd.*
            FROM transactions as t
              Inner JOIN exp_channel_titles as ct
                on (t.restaurant_id = ct.entry_id)
              Inner JOIN exp_channel_data as cd
                on (ct.entry_id = cd.entry_id)
              inner join exp_members as em
                on (t.cardid - 10000000 = em.member_id)
            WHERE ct.title = '$email'
            ORDER BY t.created DESC";

$results = $this->EE->db->query($query);
```